# Convert a json text with attributes to xml

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have the following json, which is converted from a XML.

```
{  
    "@number":"0",
    "Field":[  
        {  
            "@key":"status",
            "a":"1"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i use `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode()` function to convert this back to XML it gives me following exception.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlDocumentWrapper' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IXmlElement'.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "Root");

//output
<Root number="0">
 <Field key="status">
   <a>1</a>
 </Field>
</Root>
```

This is working without a problem. Be aware that `@number` and `@key` will be attributes of specific nodes!